# Как сделать быструю галерею в OnGUI() Unity?

Tags: c#, unity3d, unity3d-editor

У меня есть галерея объектов в Unity, :
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Она начинает тормозить очень сильно когда там 1160 объектов. Как мне улучшить свой код ? Да и как выполнять один раз то что в `void OnGUI()`, сейчас если я ставлю условия `(if(!_m_Pos.Equals(temp_m_Pos)))` такое :

```
...
    protected Vector2 _m_Pos;
    protected Vector2 temp_m_Pos;
...

    void OnGUI()
    {
        DrawLayouts();
        DrawHeader();
        DrawLeft();
        DrawRight();
        DrawFooter();
    }
...
    void DrawLeft() {
        GUILayout.BeginArea(LeftSection);
        GUILayout.BeginVertical();
        if( myList != null && myList.Count > 1 && myList[1] != null ) {
            if(treeBool==false) {
                _m_Pos = GUILayout.BeginScrollView(_m_Pos, false, true,GUILayout.Width(LeftSection.width), GUILayout.Height(LeftSection.height-20));
                int count = 0; 
                if(!_m_Pos.Equals(temp_m_Pos)) {
                   ...
                   temp_m_Pos=_m_Pos;
                }
                GUILayout.EndScrollView();
            } else {
                m_SimpleTreeView.OnGUI(new Rect(0, 0, LeftSection.width, LeftSection.height-20));
            }

        } else {
            GUILayout.Label("Объекты не определены, определите объекты.");
        }

        treeBool = GUI.Toggle (new Rect (0, LeftSection.height-20, 100, 20), treeBool, "Дерево");

        GUILayout.EndVertical();
        GUILayout.EndArea();
    }
```

Перестают отрисовываться объекты.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Сам код галереи :

```
void DrawLeft() {
    GUILayout.BeginArea(LeftSection);
    GUILayout.BeginVertical();
    if( myList != null && myList.Count > 1 && myList[1] != null ) {
        if(treeBool==false) {
            _m_Pos = GUILayout.BeginScrollView(_m_Pos, false, true,GUILayout.Width(LeftSection.width), GUILayout.Height(LeftSection.height-20));
            int count = 0; 
            if(_m_Pos.Equals(temp_m_Pos)) {
                for(int l=0;l<myList.Count;l++) {
                    Texture2D myOtherTex = LoadTexture(myList[l].url_texture);
                    Texture tex = myOtherTex as Texture;
                    double countColumn = Math.Floor((double)LeftSection.width/tex.width);
                    if(l % (int)countColumn == 0) {
                        count = 0;
                        if(count==0)
                            GUILayout.BeginHorizontal();
                        if (GUILayout.Button(tex)) {
                            // SelectKeyString = myList[l].key;
                            // Debug.Log(myList[l].key);
                            SelectObject(l);
                        }
                    } else {
                        if (GUILayout.Button(tex)) {
                            // SelectKeyString = myList[l].key;
                            // Debug.Log(myList[l].key);
                            SelectObject(l);
                        }
                        count++;
                        if(count==(int)countColumn-1||l==myList.Count-1)
                            GUILayout.EndHorizontal();
                    }
                }
                temp_m_Pos=_m_Pos;
            }
            GUILayout.EndScrollView();
        } else {
            m_SimpleTreeView.OnGUI(new Rect(0, 0, LeftSection.width, LeftSection.height-20));
        }

    } else {
        GUILayout.Label("Объекты не определены, определите объекты.");
    }

    treeBool = GUI.Toggle (new Rect (0, LeftSection.height-20, 100, 20), treeBool, "Дерево");

    GUILayout.EndVertical();
    GUILayout.EndArea();
}
```

Вообще можно заставить работать быстрее то что постоянно отрисовывается в `void OnGUI()` ?

Profiler:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Для начала: GUILayout - это довольно медленная штука. (Кстати говоря, почему GUILayout в Editor коде? Разницы то конечно нет, но в целом лучше все же использовать EditorGUILayout.

Comment: Также не совсем понятно, почему на каждом вызове OnGUI вы заново загружаете текстуры? Особенно если это связано с интернетом, насколько я помню один из ваших прошлых вопросов.

Comment: Идея с "кэшированием" картинки из OnGUI не сработает ну никак - Unity автоматически чистит окно, а потом вызывает OnGUI для сразу кучи вещей - layout/repaint, проверку событий и всякое такое прочее.

Comment: Но все же я думаю, что основной боттлнек в подгрузке картинок при каждой отрисовке, хотя и автоматическая верстка вносит свое. Хотя для пущей уверенности можно поставить парочку `Profiler.BeginSample` и прогнать свой GUI через профайлер (да, профайлер может даже редактор проверять).

Comment: @RiotBr3aker Нет это не связано с интернетом. Я беру картины в папке(Assets\Resources\Icon). Сейчас читаю про Profiler.BeginSample

Comment: @RiotBr3aker заменил где возможно на EditorGUILayout. Особо не читал про разницу между EditorGUILayout и GUILayout

Comment: Ну хорошо, вы **каждый** апдейт грузите 1160 файлов с диска, это уже побыстрее интернета, но тем не менее это очень сильно тормозит весь GUI. Уверен, что весь ботлнек в этом.

Comment: `EditorGUILayout` и `GUILayout` не сильно отличаются, в первом варианте немного больше функционала, а так они идентичны. Просто немного странно для редактора использовать не EditorGUI.

Comment: @RiotBr3aker я не понимаю как посмотреть статистику что грузит систему с помощью Profiler запихнул код в  Profiler.BeginSample("MyPieceOfCode");Profiler.EndSample(); Но статистика отображается только когда запускаю игру

Comment: Наверху окна профайлера есть кнопка `Profile Editor`. Также надо понимать, что OnGUI будет вызываться только когда вы посылаете какое-то событие окну GUI. Самое простое - поводите по нему мышкой и смотрите в окно профайлера.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/99996/discussion-between-ivan-triumphov-and-riotbr3aker).

Answer (score 0):

Предварительная загрузка изображений существенно исправила ситуацию:

```
    Texture2D myOtherTex = LoadTexture(myList[l].url_texture);
    Texture tex = myOtherTex as Texture;
```

перенёс в `void OnEnable()`
 Код теперь выглядит так :

```
        void OnEnable()
        {
            InitTextures();
            // GamObjTextFieldPrefabObjURL = new GameObject();
            InitOnGUI();
            ODBtemp = new ObjectDataBase();
            myList = ODBtemp.SelectAllObjMap();

            if (m_TreeViewState == null)
                m_TreeViewState = new TreeViewState ();

            m_SimpleTreeView = new SimpleTreeView(m_TreeViewState);

            TextureObj = new List<Texture>();
            for(int l=0;l<myList.Count;l++) {
                Texture2D myOtherTex = LoadTexture(myList[l].url_texture);
                Texture tex = myOtherTex as Texture;
                TextureObj.Add(tex);
                // List <GUILayout.Button> tempButton;
            }

        }
    ...

        void DrawLeft() {
            GUILayout.BeginArea(LeftSection);
            EditorGUILayout.BeginVertical();
            if( myList != null && myList.Count > 1 && myList[1] != null ) {
                if(treeBool==false) {
                    Profiler.BeginSample("MyPieceOfCode");
                    _m_Pos = EditorGUILayout.BeginScrollView(_m_Pos, false, true,GUILayout.Width(LeftSection.width), GUILayout.Height(LeftSection.height-20));
                    int count = 0;
                    for(int l=0;l<myList.Count;l++) {
                        // Texture2D myOtherTex = LoadTexture(myList[l].url_texture);
                        // Texture tex = myOtherTex as Texture;
                        double countColumn = Math.Floor((double)LeftSection.width/TextureObj[l].width);
                        if(l % (int)countColumn == 0) {
                            count = 0;
                            if(count==0)
                                EditorGUILayout.BeginHorizontal();
                            if (GUILayout.Button(TextureObj[l])) {
                                SelectObject(l);
                            }
                        } else {
                            if (GUILayout.Button(TextureObj[l])) {
                                SelectObject(l);
                            }
                            count++;
                            if(count==(int)countColumn-1||l==myList.Count-1)
                                EditorGUILayout.EndHorizontal();
                        }
                    }
                    temp_m_Pos=_m_Pos;
                    EditorGUILayout.EndScrollView();
                    Profiler.EndSample();
                } else {
                    m_SimpleTreeView.OnGUI(new Rect(0, 0, LeftSection.width, LeftSection.height-20));
                }

            } else {
                GUILayout.Label("Объекты не определены, определите объекты.");
            }

            treeBool = GUI.Toggle (new Rect (0, LeftSection.height-20, 100, 20), treeBool, "Дерево");

            EditorGUILayout.EndVertical();
            GUILayout.EndArea();
        }
...
    void OnGUI()
    {
        DrawLayouts();
        DrawHeader();
        DrawLeft();
        DrawRight();
        DrawFooter();
    }
```

Comment: Так то можно было и мне ответ оставить :^(

Comment: @RiotBr3aker Так оставляйте , я его помечу как правильный

Comment: Да ладно, принимайте уже этот :)